# Paypal Sandbox cannot create Buyer account

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

Is Paypal sandbox still operational ?  or is it an empty nutshell not usable anymore ?  After creating correctly a Merchant Sandbox Account, I ma now fighting with PP sandbox to create a simple Buyer Sandbox Account....  the status is first processing then it comes to error without any additional information !!!

What's make me mad , is this (Hamlet's) info message displayed ( success or not success, that is the question)

```
Your sandbox account was successfully created.
```

[image: paypal sandbox accounts]

Then nothing happen anymore...
And If I refresh the page I get

[image: paypal sandbox accounts with error]

Looking into the Profile of this error account.. I can see all the details of the account (settings, etc...) with the following information at the bottom:

```
Your sandbox account could not be created. Delete it and try again.
```

Am I wrong somewhere ? or is the sandbox not working correctly ?

**UPDATE 1**

It seems I can only create Merchant ( Business) accounts ... I added one more andd used it as a buyer... but doing this bypass the issue, it does not solved it

UPDATE 2

I tried to used a buyer sandbox account ven with the error status displayed ... and It works !!  so this is a PP bug....

Answer (score 0):

This is a PayPal bug without any incidence on the createc buyer accounts...
I used them despite the (error' status on the dashboard and they work fine ..